# VB.Net is not catching stored procedure raiserror

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, try-catch, raiseerror

Has someone already encountered this error like the stored procedure raise an error but the client (vb.net) did not catch the error?

Below is my code calling the stored procedure from vb.net

```
Try

       Dim exec_refreshdependentviews As String = String.Format("EXEC REFRESHDEPENDENTVIEWS '{0}', '{1}', {2} ", tableName, usercode, isCreateNew)

       Using refreshCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(exec_refreshdependentviews, DirectCast(sqlTransaction.Connection, SqlClient.SqlConnection), DirectCast(sqlTransaction, SqlClient.SqlTransaction))                  
               refreshCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       End Using
Catch exc As SqlClient.SqlException
        Throw New Exception("REFRESHDEPENDENTVIEWS", exc)
Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("REFRESHDEPENDENTVIEWS", ex)
End Try
```

Inside the stored procedure I raised an error, whose message was from the accumulated error encountered inside the SP.

```
RAISERROR  (@Errors, 16, 1)
```

Please note the @Errors has a value.

When I tried to run the script thru backend, I can see error message message in Message tab.

```
EXEC RefreshDependentViews 'CustomerSalesOrder', 'admin', 1
```

Below is the accumulated error message.

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 6, Procedure RefreshDependentViews, Line
>   216 Invalid object name 'dbo._Merged_SalesOrder_with_Details'. Msg
>   50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RefreshDependentViews, Line 216
>   Invalid object name 'Hips54.dbo.SupplierPurchaseReceiptDetailView'.
>   Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RefreshDependentViews, Line
>   299 Error running RefreshDependentViews CustomerSalesOrder: Failed to
>   SP_REFRESHVIEW _Merged_SalesOrder_. Message: Invalid object name
>   'dbo._Merged_SalesOrder_with_Details'. Error running
>   RefreshDependentViews CustomerSalesOrder: Failed to SP_REFRESHVIEW
>   _SOG_New. Message: Invalid object name 'Hips54.dbo.SupplierPurchaseReceiptDetailView'.

The above error was not catch by the try-catch in vb.net. It's like there's no error raised in my SP

Comment: Where in the SP is the `RAISERROR` placed?

Comment: Show your SP code. VB.NET will catch the error if the SP throws one.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified you code to just querying the exeption

```
Try
  Using refreshCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("RAISERROR  ('test', 16, 1)", cn)
      refreshCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
Catch exc As SqlClient.SqlException
  Throw New Exception("REFRESHDEPENDENTVIEWS", exc)
Catch ex As Exception
  Throw New Exception("REFRESHDEPENDENTVIEWS", ex)
End Try
```

And it throws exception caught by the first catch as expected. So it seems that the problem is the stored procedure. I would try to change severity (16 -> 20) to supprest possible catches in server code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I found now the culprit.

In my code, I'm using the sqlTransaction in the SqlClient.SqlCommand, which is the cause of the issue why the raiserror wasn't catch by the try-catch block.

Below were my code that causes the issue:

```
sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
Me.RefreshDependentViews(connectionString, objectsToRefresh(i), m_UserCode)
sqlTransaction.Commit()
```

My code in stored procedure

```
DECLARE @Errors NVARCHAR(MAX), @Error NVARCHAR(100)
BEGIN TRY              
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXEC RefreshTableColletionOnView @TableName, @UserCode
    COMMIT TRANSACTION          
END TRY              
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    SET @Error = 'Warning: Failed to RefreshDataDictionaryColumn ' + @tablename
    IF @Errors IS NULL
        SET @Errors = @Error + '.' + CHAR(13) + 'Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    ELSE
        SET @Errors = @Errors + @Error + '.' + CHAR(13) + 'Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH

IF @Errors IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (@Errors, 16, 1)              
END
```

I don't know the reason why @Errors is empty when the SP was called thru VB.Net but if I run it thru MSSQL the @Errors has error value.